# Java: XML generation with DOM and unescapeHtml4()

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a source text file that contains a bunch of regular expression.
I am reading the textfile, assigning regex matches to array indices, and creating XML using DOM.

However, there is some boilerplate information I need to add to the resulting XML document. Instead of creating hundreds of new, complex nested DOM elements, I want to just drop the XML boilerplate information into one of the XML DOM elements using element.setTextContent(someBoilerPlateXML).

I'm trying org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4 to do this. It seems to work for my System.out.println(someBoilerPlateXML) tests, but not in the element.setTextContent(someBoilerPlateXML) implementation.

For example:

Input:
`String test = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("<Hello id=\"id\"/>");
        System.out.println(test);`

Output:
        `<Hello id="id"/>`

Input:     `Element element= doc.createElement("element");

element.setTextContent(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("<Hello id=\"id\">"));`

Output in resulting XML file: 
        `&lt;Hello id="id"/&gt`

Why does it do this, and how can I make it right? Is there another free package out there that I need to use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.setTextContent` will, as you discovered, escape the text you feed it rather than recognize and handle it as xml.

If you have a text representation of xml that you want to add as xml, you'll need to deal with it as xml, which means parsing it into a DOM `Node` and then appending it in that form.

If your text is not a complete xml, this won't work.  In your example, you have only a start tag, which can't be parsed to make a `Node`.

But if it is complete and you've found it easier to produce as text, you can do something like this:

```
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = documentBuilder.newDocument();
    Element element= doc.createElement("element");
    doc.appendChild(element);

    Document newDoc = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<Hello id=\"id\"/>")));

    Element newElement = newDoc.getDocumentElement();
    Node node = doc.importNode(newElement, true);

    element.appendChild(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how the xml text content is escaped you will get back your original text when you read it back

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
Element element= doc.createElement("element");
element.setTextContent("<Hello id=\"id\">");
doc.appendChild(element);

Transformer trf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
trf.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out));
System.out.println();
System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
```

prints out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><element>&lt;Hello id="id"&gt;</element>
<Hello id="id">
```

Comment: No, I meant element.setTextContent(someXML) doesn't work in the file. Though, you're right that System.out.println() does work.